# Which chars are valid shortopts for GNU getopt?

Tags: bash, getopt

I would like to know which chars are valid shortopts for the GNU getopt, which is implemented in many different languages, like Bash or PHP.

I didn't find an official documentation where it is defined, or I have overread it.

I tested following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a%2" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    %)
      echo "-% was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    2)
      echo "-2 was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

The result:

```
$ ./test -a%2x
-a was triggered!
-% was triggered!
-2 was triggered!
Invalid option: -x
```

So I can tell that at least -% and -2 are valid short opts, or the getopt implementation of Bash is not correct.

Which characters are excluded/illegal short opts? I know that ':' is excluded, obviously, and that '?' is defined as always illegal, therefore '-?' is mostly used to show an usage information page.

Comment: Shot in the dark from a non-Linux user, here: could it be that you're calling `getopts` with the argument `:a%2`, and only valid characters in that list are allowed? So if you use `while getopts ":a%2x" opt; do...` instead it would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html) says:

> All option characters allowed by Utility Syntax Guideline 3 are allowed in *optstring*. The implementation may accept other characters as an extension.

[Guideline 3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) says:

> Each option name should be a single alphanumeric character (the **alnum** character classification) from the portable character set. The **-W** (capital-W) option shall be reserved for vendor options.
>   Multi-digit options should not be allowed.

In turn, the [**alnum** class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html) is defined as these characters:

> ```
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

The Linux [`getopt(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) manpage says:

> The use of '+' and '-' in *optstring* is a GNU extension.

So it accepts those as well. If others work for you, I guess that's good, but beware of making use of undocumented behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful answer, I searched very long for that! Additional question: I know that the shortopt '-' has usually the meaning to cancel the option parsing (e.g. `command -x -y -- file1 file2`) . But does the shortopt '+' have a special meaning? I never saw a command that would have `command -+` as syntax. As far as I see, the '+' is only useful in `optstring` to enable the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` behavior, but can/should not be used as actual CLI argument.

Comment: That seems the likely case. I don't have any citations handy right now though.

Comment: Do you know if longopts also only may use the alnum class? I searched very long, but I don't find a reference that explains the valid syntax